# how to find the optimal values for parameter in_range and out_range for sklearn.exposure.rescale_intensity

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

If I use `(0,100)` my image becomes totally white and if I use `(300,700)` it becomes completely white. Do I need to brute-check every value every time I use `in_range` or is there some optimal values for both the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity) for `rescale_intensity` states

```
in_range, out_rangestr or 2-tuple, optional

    [...]

    ‘image’
        Use image min/max as the intensity range.
    [...]
```

So, if you set `in_range='image'`, which is the default anyway, the min and max of the image will be used for the range and the output image will always have maximum contrast between black and white.

Comment: but I want to change the intensity  of the image. This the only problem

Comment: the default values will stretch the image from its min/max to 0-1 for float images or 0-255 for uint8 images